# Sorting a PS list based on an enumerated types textual name

Tags: powershell

If I run the following then the list of Status names is not sorted alphabetically descending:

```
get-service | Sort-Object status -Descending
```

I understand that the `status` is an enumerated type and therefore the sortint will be based on these values:

```
[enum]::GetValues("System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus") | Select Value__
```

But how do i amend the original command so that is sorts the list descending based on the textual value of the status?

Comment: Try `Get-Service | Sort-Object { $_.Status.ToString() } -Descending`

Comment: If you want to further sort your results so you get all the stopped / running services alphabetically ordered by a second criteria, such as the display name, you can expand on Theo's answer to do something like  `Get-Service | Sort-Object @{'e' = {$_.Status.ToString()};descending = $true},DisplayName`